# I'm not able to understand that why am I getting a System.InvalidCastException when I'm not using any Integer?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to fetch the Purchase Date from the DataGridView and compare it with the string from the textbox, if they are equal the current record in the DataGridView is selected.
**But I am getting "$exception  {"Conversion from string ""Purchase_Date"" to type 'Integer' is not valid."}    System.InvalidCastException".** I don't understand why am I getting this exception even though I am not using an Integer?

Below is the code where I am facing this issue:

```vb
        Dim i = 0
        For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In dgPurchases.Rows
            Dim currentdate As String = Format(dgPurchases.Rows("Purchase_Date").ToString(),
            "dd/MM/yyyy")
            If StrComp(currentdate, purchasedate) Then
                dgPurchases.Rows(i).Selected = True
            End If
            i += 1
        Next
```

Comment: I don't think you meant `dgPurchases.Rows("Purchase_Date")`.  `Rows` is expecting and integer argument.

Comment: Other than what's mentioned in my answer, there's a lot wrong with that code.  Firstly, you get a value from a column named `Purchase_Date` and assign it to a variable named `currentdate` and then compare that to a variable named `purchasedate`. Either you are using the wrong variables or you have named your variables very poorly.

Comment: On top of that, you should not be comparing `Strings` in order to compare dates.  You should be comparing `Dates`.  If you wouldn't convert numbers to `Strings` to compare them (please tell me you don't) then why would you convert `Dates`?

Comment: I'm going to assume that `currentdate` is actually today's date and `purchasedate` is the value from the grid.  In that case, you can just do something like this: `If CDate(row.Cells("Purchase_Date")) = Date.Today Then`.  The principle stands no matter what dates you're dealing with.  Leave `Dates` as `Dates`.  `Strings` are for display or data that is genuinely text, e.g. names, only.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense that you are using a `For Each` loop and keeping a counter.  Make up your mind whether you want a `For` loop or a `For Each` loop and then use the one you choose properly.

If you choose a `For Each` loop, use the loop control variable:

```vb
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgPurchases.Rows
    Dim currentdate As String = Format(row.Cells("Purchase_Date"), "dd/MM/yyyy")

    If StrComp(currentdate, purchasedate) Then
        row.Selected = True
    End If
Next
```

If you choose a `For` loop then it provides a loop counter:

```vb
For i = 0 To dgPurchases.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim currentdate As String = Format(dgPurchases.Rows(i).Cells("Purchase_Date"), "dd/MM/yyyy")

    If StrComp(currentdate, purchasedate) Then
        dgPurchases.Rows(i).Selected = True
    End If
Next
```

The `For Each` loop is clearly superior when the only thing you'd use a loop counter for is indexing a single list.

I should have mentioned specifically that the part that addresses your question as asked is that the column name is used to index the `Cells` collection of the row, not the `Rows` collection of the grid.